# What is the minimum time required for a delay activity to cause a persist?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I am trying to force a workflow service to persist (for "recovery/restart" purposes) and need to know if there is a minimum delay required to force a persist of the workflow. In most cases, I would do a bit of testing and see if I could determine the minimum, but am in a crunch because it appears that an alternate method is not working for me. The service is configured to immediately persist by the following, which is in my web.config:

```
<workflowIdle timeToUnload="0"/>
```

So, if I do a delay of, say, one second, will this be enough to force a persist? Should I just add a Persist activity rather than the delay? Or must I just try values until it either works or I determine I have to move on to another method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workflowIdle behavior kicks in when a workflow enters the Idle state.  This will occur even with a delay as short as 1ms.

However, based on your requirement it is better to use the Persist activity to force persistence.

Comment: How can I determine if the workflow is in a "No Persist Zone" where a call to Persist won't work? I remember trying to add Persist activities but ended up having some exceptions related to being in a "No Persist Zone"

Comment: @MarkMcDowell_TRM Check this blog post [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2010/08/22/workflows-and-no-persist-zones.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, Jota. This helps if I am in code. What if I'm looking at a workflow in the designer. How can I tell outside of code/in the designer (without the "add a persist, run and see if it fails with a No Persist Zone message" try it and see loop) so I can "predict" where the No Persist Zones are without experimentation each time.

Comment: No Persist Zones are typically created by "Scope" type activities like the TransactionScope with the one exception of messaging activities with a Send/ReceiveReply or Receive/SendReply.  There is no good visual indicator of a NoPersistZone and in fact at design time we cannot know if an activity implements a No Persist Zone in code.

Comment: So, effectively, to find out I have to attempt a persist and see if it fails... Rats. Thanks for the information, Ron and Jota.